# USB 3.0 doesn't work after waking up from suspend

Tags: usb, suspend, wakeup

I tried a few things but my problem is still here. If I restart my PC, USB devices work well. However, after waking up from suspend, the two USB 3.0 ports don't work but the USB 2.0 ports work well.

Comment: Sounds like a kernel bug, What kernel do you have? What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: 13.04, also same problem in 12.04 too..

Comment: intel i5 - samsung series 9 ultrabook NP900X4D

Comment: What Linux Kernel version do you have? look in system information of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it going into the BIOS and activating "USB S3 resume" (or something like that) option under the *advance* tab.

Hope this works for you!